# Falha na atualização das variaveis

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

Estou a desenvolver um projeto em java, um "farm game" onde existem varias stats para o personagem que é criado. 
Quando criamos uma personagem defenimos qual a sua classe, isto vai influenciar as suas stats.

O meu problema é aqui, quando escolho a class as stats não atualizam devidamente.

Codigo para escolher a classe:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Knight extends Game {

    public static PlayerClass chooseSubClass() {
        System.out.println("1 -» Heavy \n2 -» SwordsMaster \n3 -» Royal");
        int op = 0;
        while (op == 0) {
            try {
                op = Main.in.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
        PlayerClass playerClass;
        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                playerClass = new Heavy();
                break;
            case 2:
                playerClass = new Swordsmaster();
                break;
            case 3:
                playerClass = new Royal ();
                break;
            default:
                playerClass = chooseSubClass();
                break;
        }
        return playerClass;
    }
}
```

Caso se escolha heavy:

```
public class Heavy extends PlayerClass {

    public Heavy() {
        attackDamage += 50;
        armorPenetration += 20;
    }
}
```

As stats:

```
public class PlayerClass {

    public long attackDamage = 10;
    public long armorPenetration;
    public long magicDamage= 10;
    public long magicPenetration;
    public double attackSpeed= 1;
    public long money = 100;
    public int level = 1;



}
```

Codigo do player

```
public class Player extends PlayerClass{


    private String playerName;
    private PlayerClass playerClass;

    public String classes = "1 -» Knight \n2 -» Mage \n3 -» Archer";

    //Chooses the class and subclass of the player
    public void chooseClass() {

        System.out.println(classes);
        int op = Main.in.nextInt();
        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                playerClass = Knight.chooseSubClass();
                break;
            case 2:
                playerClass = Mage.chooseSubClass();
                break;
            default:
                chooseClass();
                break;
        }
    }


    // Setter method
    public void setPlayerName(String name) {
        playerName = name;
    }

    // Getter method
    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }
    public String getClassName() {
        return playerClass.getClass().getName();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisei seu código rapidamente e pelo que pude perceber o problema está no fato de você  utilizar *armorPenetration += 20* sem que a sua variável *armorPenetration* tenha um valor inicial. Nesse caso você deve escolher um valor padrão na criação da sua class, no caso *PlayerClass*.
Por exemplo, escolhendo 0 como valor inicial ficaria assim a classe:

```
public class PlayerClass {

public long attackDamage = 10;
public long armorPenetration = 0;
public long magicDamage= 10;
public long magicPenetration = 0;
public double attackSpeed= 1;
public long money = 100;
public int level = 1;

}
```

Nesses casos é sempre bom iniciar com um valor padrão quando criar uma nova classe.